# Java: multiple conversions in a single line

Tags: java, performance

Hello StackOverflow community.

Im making my first steps in Java and OOP. I would like to know ¿Is there a way to convert and argument in to another type of variable, then convert it in to an object in a single line of operation?.

Thank you for your time and help.

This is the code that isnt mine, it is from a book im reading:

```
public class Changer {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            System.out.println("The original value: "
                + arguments[0]);
            Float num1 = new Float(arguments[0]);
            float num2 = num1.floatValue();
            int num3 = (int)num2;
            System.out.println("The final value: " + num3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Give a code example to indicate what you are looking for (on multiple lines).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. This code isnt mine, i took it from a book im reading:

public class Changer {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            System.out.println("The original value: "
                + arguments[0]);
            Float num1 = new Float(arguments[0]);
            float num2 = num1.floatValue();
            int num3 = (int)num2;
            System.out.println("The final value: " + num3);
        }
    }
}

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23769956/edit) your question to add code.

Comment: Edit done Takendarkk.

Comment: Since it's near impossible to get a closed question reopened on this site, I'll answer in a comment. That code could be shortened to `System.out.println("The final value: " + (int)new Float(arguments[0]).floatValue());` The `Float` object is unnecessary waste though; a `float` primitive will do: `System.out.println("The final value: " + (int)Float.parseFloat(arguments[0]));`

Comment: This has the "performance" tag on it.  It's not generally true that putting everything on one line improves performance.  Eliminating some variables might not make a difference--the compiler may need to generate temporary variables anyway, and it could easily figure out that in the above code your variables are only used once and could eliminate some references to them.  Finally, readability is almost always orders of magnitude more important than saving a few nanoseconds here and there.

Comment: Thank you ajb i didnt know it.

Comment: @ajb You're right, and I'd go much further than saying "it is not generally true": I can't think of *any* circumstance in which joining expressions that were using explicit local variables, or splitting them again, could make Java code faster. It should be identical after compilation and JVM optimization, although I'd be interested to be proven wrong.

Comment: @ajb thank you for your time. How would you set that code to improve performance?.

Comment: @CodeNoob I wouldn't waste time trying.

Comment: @CodeNoob `float` is faster than `Float`. However, since this particular code executes only once, it will take no time either way. You should only worry about performance of those lines of code that run millions, billions or trillions of times in your program, or when you've benchmarked and determined that there is a real bottleneck. Anything else is wasting your time as a programmer, while saving no noticeable time in the program.

Comment: @Boann Thank you for your time and patience. Please write your comments as "answer" to accep it and close the question stream.

Glad to read you.

Comment: @CodeNoob Eh I can't be bothered, but I was happy to help anyway.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Hello, as you can read, i did clarify the question and i was given many proper answers. 
Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boann Answer:
float is faster than Float. However, since this particular code executes only once, it will take no time either way. You should only worry about performance of those lines of code that run millions, billions or trillions of times in your program, or when you've benchmarked and determined that there is a real bottleneck. Anything else is wasting your time as a programmer, while saving no noticeable time in the program.